# Ask for an input to define a variable

Tags: input, maxima

I want to plot an expression in Maxima. Indeed, I want from Maxima to ask me for an input and allocates that to a variable which is used in plotting, but I don't know what is the command line for asking an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[read](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_4.html#IDX34)

```
(%i1) load("draw") $
(%i2) om: read("Enter `om' followed by a semicolon (;)") $
Enter `om' followed by a semicolon (;) 
3;
(%i3) draw2d(explicit(sin(om*'x), 'x, 0, 2*%pi)) $
```

Comment: Thank you, It was too helpful.